# Proving $ |Im(z)| \leq |z| $

Tags: inequality, complex-numbers

> Prove that $$  |Im(z)| \leq  |z|$$

So far I have used that $$Im(z) = \frac{1}{2i}(z - \bar{z})$$ and $$|z| = \sqrt{z \bar{z}}.$$ I then tried to apply the reverse triangle inequality: $$|Im(z)| = \frac{1}{2}|z - \bar{z}| \geq \frac{1}{2}(|z| - |\bar{z}|) = \frac{1}{2}( \sqrt{z \bar{z}} -  \sqrt{\bar{z} {z}}) = 0$$ which clearly doesn't lead anywhere.

Would appreciate any help.

Comment: It is easier to just use $z = x+iy$ and $\operatorname{Im}(z) = y$.

Comment: What about $|y|\le\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ ? Or, in polar coordinates, $|\sin\phi|\le1$ ?

Comment: What is the definition of $|z|$ in terms of the real and imaginary parts of $z$?

Comment: $$\left|\frac{z-\bar z}{2i}\right|=\frac12|z-\bar z|\le\frac12(|z|+|\bar z|).$$

Comment: @YvesDaoust I don't really understand where this equality comes from. is it some application of the triangle inequality, or just a special case with $|z|$ and $|\bar{z}|$?

Comment: $|a\pm b|\le|a|+|b|$. In the accepted answer, you find this very inequality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have\begin{align}|\operatorname{Im}z|&=\left|\frac{z-\overline z}{2i}\right|\\&\leqslant\frac{|z|+\left|\overline z\right|}2\\&=\frac{|z|+|z|}2\\&=|z|.\end{align}Note that $|z|=\left|\overline z\right|$ because\begin{align}\left|\overline z\right|^2&=\overline z.\overline{\overline z}\\&=\overline z.z\\&=|z|^2.\end{align}

Answer (score 4):

Let $z = x+i y$.

Then just observe that since $y^2\le x^2+y^2$, so $|y| \le \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, that is $|\mathrm{Im}(z)| \le |z|$.

Bonus: equality happens exactly when $x=0$, in other words, when $z$ is purely imaginary.

Comment: +1 : In light of the other responses, the only thing missing from your answer is the opening statement: $x$ and $y$ say hello.